# scipy.stats.t.logsf infinite values

Tags: python, scipy

I have a t score of 69.667, when my degrees of freedom are 726 logsf returns the following:

```
>>> scipy.stats.t.logsf(69.667, 726)
-744.4400719213812
```

However at df = 727 I get the following

```
>>> scipy.stats.t.logsf(69.667, 727)
-inf
```

Can someone explain how I am hitting the number limit here? The reason I used the log survival function is to avoid this issue. Is there any other way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [implementation of the t distribution](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/b4bfa9de3e838122d31722194dc273fffeabadf0/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py#L5215) in SciPy doesn't override the `_logsf` method, so it defaults to computing the log of the sf function:

```
In [24]: t.sf(69.667, [726, 727])                                                                                                                                    
Out[24]: array([5.e-324, 0.e+000])

In [25]: np.log(t.sf(69.667, [726, 727]))                                                                                                                            
/.../ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log

Out[25]: array([-744.44007192,          -inf])
```

By the way, 5e-324 is the smallest magnitude nonzero 64 bit floating point number (it is a [denormal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number)), so that result has just 1 bit of precision.  Don't put too much faith in all those digits in -744.44007192 returned by `t.logsf(69.667, 726)`.